# What does it mean to open a RandomAccessFile in Java?

Tags: java, randomaccessfile

RandomAccessFile has a close() method with the following description:

> Closes this random access file stream and releases any system resources associated with the stream.

What does it mean to open a RandomAccessFile? I'm asking because there does is no open() method. Is opening a RandomAccessFile just implicit when we perform tasks like reading and writing? Why is there no open() method? Does it make sense to only open a RandomAccessFile without performing any other tasks simultaneously?

Comment: How come there is no `open` on `File` either? The basic io api operates on streams, just go through the relevant oracle tutorial.

Comment: I never thought to read the oracle documentation. Thanks for your insight.

Answer (score 1):

as stated in Java doc the file is created using the constructor
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html

> RandomAccessFile(File file, String mode) Creates a random access file
>   stream to read from, and optionally to write to, the file specified by
>   the File argument.
>
> RandomAccessFile(String name, String mode) Creates a random access
>   file stream to read from, and optionally to write to, a file with the
>   specified name.

To be precise :

> Creates a random access file stream to read from, and optionally to
>   write to, a file with the specified name. A new FileDescriptor object
>   is created to represent the connection to the file. The mode argument
>   specifies the access mode with which the file is to be opened. The
>   permitted values and their meanings are as specified for the
>   RandomAccessFile(File,String) constructor.
>
> If there is a security manager, its checkRead method is called with
>   the name argument as its argument to see if read access to the file is
>   allowed. If the mode allows writing, the security manager's checkWrite
>   method is also called with the name argument as its argument to see if
>   write access to the file is allowed.

Since there is no explicit destructor in Java (to my knowledge), you need to close the file explicitly once you created a RandomAccessFile.

Comment: So once we close the RandomAccessFile, the stream is closed and we would have to instantiate a new one in order to "rw" on the file again?

Comment: i did not test it myslef, but that's how I get it from the java doc. Do a mini project of 2 line sto convince yourself :)

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new instance of `RandomAccessFile` object it's like call implicitly the open method.
During the creation of the object also a new FileDescriptor object is created to represent the connection to the file.

I suggest to create this object using the [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement, because  `RandomAccessFile` implements the interface `java.lang.AutoCloseable`.

```
try (RandomAccessFile stmt = new RandomAccessFile("file.txt", "rw")) {
  // your code
} catch (IOException e) {
  // Exception handling
}
```